# Understanding Node.js Resident Set Size vs. Heap Size (OOM errors)

Tags: node.js

I'm fighting against a problem in my node server where I get an error that causes the node app to crash:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I'm using nodetime to take a look at the memory usage. I think perhaps I'm narrowing down on the problem, but I'm still pretty confused. Check out this function, which uses Mongoose to load a cached object from MongoDB:

```
StreamCache.prototype.loadCachedStream = function(_id, callback)
{
    this.model.findOne({'_id': _id}, {'objects':1,'last_updated':1}, function(err, d){
        callback(err, d ? d.toObject() : null);
        //The toObject() seems to cause the RSS to move into heap...?
    });
};
```

Notice the commented line. Prior to 11pm last night, the line was just

```
callback(err,d);
```

I added the toObject() call at 11pm last night.

Now look at my memory charts:

[image]

Notice that prior to this change, the RSS grew but not the heap. After the change, the heap and RSS grew exactly the same (until the app crashed). Note that the out of memory error (above) was happening both before and after the change. However, the change seems to have made the heap size correlate in its leaks to the RSS size, where before the heap was flat(ish).

My assumption is that, for some reason, this means the toObject() function moved the leaked data from RSS into the heap, so not only the RSS was leaking but also the heap.

Does that sound right?

If so... any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Did you try taking and comparing heap snapshots at start and at the leak-time? Does it reveal anything? In Nodetime you could save the first snapshot (well, just take a screenshot or save the html for now) to later visually compare it with leak-time snapshot. Note: taking heap snapshots may double the memory used by the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think Heap/RSS correlation is irrelevant to the out of memory problem you are experiencing.

(What's the difference between the two anyways?, one is the total amount of virtual memory used, the other is what is in the physical RAM at the moment in which case it just means that the change introduced data structures that OS (OS) has decided are important to keep in the physical RAM, e.g. because they are accessed often)

What you are saying the cause of the problem is in d.toJSON() call, why do you think that toJSON() alone won't cause out of memory error?

What if the "d" object is so huge, say it's a root of the big object tree that consumes all the memory when it's getting deserialized into the JSON string?

Comment: The "toJSON()" function of Mongoose does not actually turn the object into a JSON string; in fact, it reduces the size of the object (see docs). The "d" object is a document, and the result of the toJSON() function is a standard object appropriate for later output. Thus, I'm confused by what you mean by "toJSON() alone..." toJSON can only be called on a Mongoose document...

Comment: I changed my question to use "toObject" instead of "toJSON" since they are actually analogous in this case within Mongoose, and "toObject" is much clearer nomenclature. Also -- my point was that, since this change caused the heap to correlate to the RSS, it seems a logical conclusion that this object is the leaking object (I'm not  concerned with RSS vs. heap, per se, but simply what object is leaking and why).

Comment: you are correct my assumption about the call returning the json string was wrong, but I still think the toJSON or toObject may be the culprit as it tries to create a pojo potentially serializing the return results of all the properties that exist on the document but which may be using lazy instantiation when accessed. Here you are going over every single prop of the document and instantiating a String value for it.  No?

Comment: Note that I said the leak was happening **even before the toObject call was added**. The only change the toObject call did was to make the source of the presumed source of the memory leak more evident by showing it on the heap. In other words, the toObject() call is what made me hone in on this particular line of code as the presumed source of the leak. My question is not about fixing the toObject() call, it is about the memory leak itself.

Comment: sorry I got confused, you referred to the charts and the time of the change 11pm and all I see on the charts is that at around 11pm there was a huge increase in memory consumption followed by the crash.

Comment: True; the toObject() seems to have exacerbated the issue, but I'm trying to identify the root issue itself ;)